# HTML CANVAS not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

I have the following canvas code:

```js
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
      prevX = 0,
      currX = 0,
      prevY = 0,
      currY = 0,
      dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
      y = 2;

    function init() {
      canvas = document.getElementById('can');
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      w = canvas.width;
      h = canvas.height;

      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        findxy('move', e)
      }, false);
      canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        findxy('down', e)
      }, false);
      canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
        findxy('up', e)
      }, false);
      canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
        findxy('out', e)
      }, false);
    }

    function color(obj) {
      switch (obj.id) {

        case "blue":
          x = "blue";
          break;
        case "red":
          x = "red";
          break;

        case "black":
          x = "black";
          break;
        case "white":
          x = "white";
          break;
      }
      if (x == "white") y = 14;
      else y = 2;

    }

    function draw() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
      ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
      ctx.strokeStyle = x;
      ctx.lineWidth = y;
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
    }

    function erase() {
      var m = confirm("Want to clear");
      if (m) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    function save() {
      document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
      document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
      document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
    }

    function findxy(res, e) {
      if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.fillStyle = x;
          ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
          ctx.closePath();
          dot_flag = false;
        }
      }
      if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
      }
      if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
          prevX = currX;
          prevY = currY;
          currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
          currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
          draw();
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row 50% third">
  <div class="12u">
    <canvas class="image fit" id="can" style=" background-color:rgb(250,250,250); "></canvas>
    <div style="width:5%;height:30px;background:blue;" id="blue" class="colors" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="width:5%;height:30px;background:red;" id="red" class="colors" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="width:5%;height:30px;background:black;" id="black" class="colors" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="width:5%;height:30px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" class="colors" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:10%;">
    <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:15%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have set my body onload to init();

However, the canvas does not work.

**EDIT: The canvas works when i provide it a specific width and height in the html, but i find that my drawing and mouse is always off by a little. Is there also a way to use percentage widths and heights?
The  w = canvas.width;
      h = canvas.height;
Seems to be the one causing the problem.**

Comment: When I create a fiddle for it everything seems to work, please be more specific on **what** is not working...

Comment: hi there, in my html i didnt specify the width and height, and i think that is whats causing the issue.

Comment: when i give it a percentage width/height, the canvas stops working, when i use pixels, it works but the drawing is off by a little, currently you can see that the width/height of the canvas is determined by the class image fit, which uses percentages

Comment: When using a 2D or 3D canvas context your canvas **needs to have** pixel based `width` and `height` attributes. Also I cant see any offset here in chrome, you may want to provide a full testcase.

Comment: hmm, if i use a pixel based width and height, it does not scroll/resize well

Comment: i have a feeling that the width and height in my case is causing the issue, causing all of the drawing to be slanted OFF of the canvas

Comment: Read my comment on toms post. Its probably your CSS causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems ok to me. I added a call to the `init` function.

As LJ_1102 stated:
The offset issue is a CSS issue. [The width and height attributes set the width and height of the bitmap itself.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-canvas-width) The CSS width and height attributes set the element width and height. So, think about the `canvas` tag as if it were an `img` tag. If you set the CSS width of an `img`, it would stretch. Canvas will do the same thing.

```js
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
  prevX = 0,
  currX = 0,
  prevY = 0,
  currY = 0,
  dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
  y = 2;

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('can');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;

  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    findxy('move', e)
  }, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    findxy('down', e)
  }, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    findxy('up', e)
  }, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    findxy('out', e)
  }, false);
}

function color(obj) {
  switch (obj.id) {

    case "blue":
      x = "blue";
      break;
    case "red":
      x = "red";
      break;

    case "black":
      x = "black";
      break;
    case "white":
      x = "white";
      break;
  }
  if (x == "white") y = 14;
  else y = 2;

}

function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
  ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = x;
  ctx.lineWidth = y;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
  var m = confirm("Want to clear");
  if (m) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function save() {
  document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
  document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
}

function findxy(res, e) {
  if (res == 'down') {
    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
    currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    flag = true;
    dot_flag = true;
    if (dot_flag) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = x;
      ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
      ctx.closePath();
      dot_flag = false;
    }
  }
  if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
    flag = false;
  }
  if (res == 'move') {
    if (flag) {
      prevX = currX;
      prevY = currY;
      currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
      draw();
    }
  }
}
init();
```

```html
<div class="row 50% third">
  <div class="12u">
    <canvas class="image fit" id="can" width="50%" height="50%" style=" background-color:rgb(250,250,250); "></canvas>
    <div style="width:5%;height:30px;background:blue;" id="blue" class="colors" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="width:5%;height:30px;background:red;" id="red" class="colors" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="width:5%;height:30px;background:black;" id="black" class="colors" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <div style="width:5%;height:30px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" class="colors" onclick="color(this)"></div>
    <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:10%;">
    <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:15%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is peculiar, the code snippet looks like its working with the percentage width and height, but seemingly doesnt function on mine. would do more tests

Comment: @user4269367 I just tested on IE, Firefox, and Chrome. The only thing I changed was I added the percent widths to show that percents work and I added the call to init(). without the init() call your canvas won't be set up.

Comment: I though the canvas was styled using CSS where the 2d context does not know about the actual render size, the 2d context only cares for the attributes.

Comment: @user4269367 Try adding the call below the javascript itself or at the end of the page.

Comment: @Tom in the snippet I created it worked as `onload` attribute.

Comment: i think it was indeed a conflict in my css, possibly padding was the one causing the issue. When i shifted the canvas around to the top of the page, it worked very well without any deviation, but when i shifted it to a certain div, the problem came. Thanks anyway! I just have to figure out which div's padding to clear haha.

Comment: @user4269367 I updated my answer with the explanation about CSS width vs attribute width. That should help you understand.

Comment: yeah, i found out this is the issue, but my canvas is under a section which is under a main which is under a container and all have margins/paddings, which are messing up the canvas element

Comment: is there a way whereby i can forcefully offset where the line appears?